# Ask a technical lemma about the existence of a smooth curve between any two points on a sphere.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

This is a technical lemma about the existence of a smooth curve between any two points on a sphere.

Lemma: Let $\mathcal{S}=\{ x:||x||=r\}$, where $r>0$, and let $t_1,t_2\in \mathcal{S}$. Then there is a differentiable mapping $c:(0, 2\pi) \mapsto \mathcal{S}$ that passes through $t_1$ and $t_2$; that is, there exist $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in (0, 2\pi)$ such that $c(\alpha_1)=t_1$ and $c(\alpha_2)=t_2$.

Proof: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a hyperplane that passes through $t_1,t_2,0$ in $\mathbb R^p$. Then $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{H} \cap \mathcal{S}$ is a circle centered at the origin with radius $r$. Pick an arbitrary point $t_3$ in $\mathcal{C}$ that is not $t_1$ and $t_2$, and let $t_4$ be the point on $\mathcal{C}$ obtained by rotating $t_3$ counterclockwise 90 degree along $\mathcal{C}$. Then any point $t$ in $\mathcal{C}$ that is not $t_3$ can be written as $t=\cos(\alpha)t_3+\sin(\alpha)t_4$ for some $\alpha \in (0, 2\pi)$. By construction, $\{  c(\alpha): \alpha \in (0, 2\pi) \}$ is a differentiable curve that passes through $t_1$ and $t_2$.

**Question:** both the lemma itself and the proof look hard for me. Can I say $\mathcal{S}$ is a ball with radius r? In the proof, **why** "Then $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{H} \cap \mathcal{S}$ is a circle centered at the origin with radius $r$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S$ is the "shell" of an $n$-dimensional ball with radius $r$, as it only has the border.

For the intersection, you have a plane that passes through the center of $S$ and some points of $S$, i.e., they satisfy that their distance to the center is $r$. Finally, in a plane, the geometric space of points that have a fixed distance ($r$) to a point (the center) is a circle of radius $r$.

Comment: Thank you. You said the plane $H$ passes through the center of $S$, that is the point 0. Also passes through the some points of $S$. I know it passes through $t_1, t_2$ by the definition of $H$. Does the hyperplane $H$ pass through any other points in $S$? The other question by the intersection, what does $C$ include? I know $C$ includes $t_1, t_2$ and it doesn't include the center point 0.

Comment: Yes it passes through the hole circle of radius $r$ in the plane, lets call it $A$, this is because $p \in A \iff dist(0,p) =r$ and that implies that $p \in S$

Comment: What's the difference between A and H?

Comment: sorry for the unclear way of seing it, i mean to say that $A$ is the circle of radius $R$ and center $0$ in the plane $H$

Comment: I see. When you say "it passes through the hole circle of radius r in the plane" in the above comment, do you mean $H$ or $C$? (C is the intersection of H and S.)

Comment: what i said is proof that $H \cap S = C $ is in fact equal to $A$ (ie C is a circle with radiuos r center in 0)

Comment: What is the dimension of this intersection plane? When you say it is a circle, it looks like it is 2-dimensional?